# How to log to a log file in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, logging, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have been using Tomcat,JBoss,Glassfish etc for years.
In these containers I have used Log4j, JDK Logging etc. It is very easy.

I am struggling to get any logging from my application in Weblogic 12c.
The logs get written to stderr and not to a log file.

```
private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TestingService.class.getName()); 
log.log(Level.SEVERE,"My log " + text);
```

In the Admin console
Logging implementation: JDK
Severity level: INFO

The behaviour is the same if I configure Log4J by following the log4j Weblogic config process.

Comment: That sounds like you're fundamentally missing something. If anything, Weblogic logs way too much! Are you sure you've checked both your <domain>/servers/<server_name>/logs/server.out and <your defined path>/server.log files? There's lots of examples: http://techworldrocks.wordpress.com/2012/08/16/configure-log4j-logging-for-weblogic-server-log/

Comment: Thanks @castling. I actually grep the entire directory for the exact string in the log. If I startup weblogic with my IDE I can see it is logging to stderr. Forcing weblogic to to write stderr to the log is a ugly workaround, but it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try some codes like the following to get the Weblogic domain logger and server logger in your application:

```
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import weblogic.logging.LoggerNotAvailableException;
import weblogic.logging.LoggingHelper;
public class GetLogger {
public static Logger getLogger(){   
    Logger logger = null ;
    try {
        logger = LoggingHelper.getDomainLogger() ;
    } catch (LoggerNotAvailableException e) {
        logger = LoggingHelper.getServerLogger() ;
    }
    return logger ;
}
}
```